# Redux: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I realise there are probably a million and one different causes for this error but I am struggling to find the cause of mine. I am relatively new to Redux and state handling in the Reducer and have learned from a few examples online to come up with the code sample below which is called within the Reducer:

```
const updateTripsWhereVenueDeleted = (state, action) => {
  debugger;
  const deletedVenueId = action.venue.Id;
  const originalTrips = [...state];

  const newTrips = originalTrips.map((trip) => {
    if (trip.VenueId === deletedVenueId) {
      trip.VenueId = 0;
      trip.VenuePegId = 0;
    }
    return trip;
  });
  debugger;
  return [...newTrips];
};
```

I have **state** which is an array of Trips:

[image]

And **Action** contains a 'Venue' record.
Basically, the Venue being passed was deleted and I want to update the relevant fields on all Trips that reference the deleted Venue.

When I run the above code in the Reducer things seem to go in the right direction until the browser crashes with the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): A state mutation was
> detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `trips.0.VenueId`. Take a
> look at the reducer(s) handling the action
> {"type":"UPDATE_TRIPS_VENUE_DELETED","venue": {.... the object}

**UPDATE_TRIPS_VENUE_DELETED** is the action.type that calls my method above.

Is there an obvious mis-use of handling (spread) arrays in a state or something. I feel this should be an easy thing to do but nothing I have tried has so far worked correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spreading an object or array (`[...state]` here) does not break nested references. So you are mutating state by not making a copy of the nested object within your `map` -- `trip.VenueId = 0;`.

This leads to another observation, `map` returns a new array, so this negates the need to use `originalTrips` altogether. It is just as safe to do `state.map()`. The final spread `[...newTrips]` is definitely unnecessary as well.

To fix your mutation create a clone of the objects to be updated:

```js
const updateTripsWhereVenueDeleted = (state, action) => {

  const deletedVenueId = action.venue.Id;

  const newTrips = state.map((trip) => {
    if (trip.VenueId === deletedVenueId) {
      // Copy other trip values into NEW object and return it
      return { ...trip, VenueId: 0, VenuePegId: 0 };
    }
    // If not matched above, just return the old trip
    return trip;
  });

  return newTrips;
};
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! All makes sense and exactly what I was after! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Spread operator `...` only does shallow copy. If the array is nested or multi-dimensional, it won't work.

There are plenty of way we can do this, below are some of them

1] Deep copy using JSON

```
  const originalTrips = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));;
```

2]

```
const newTrips = originalTrips.map((trip) => {
  
    if (newTrip.VenueId === deletedVenueId) {
      let newTrip = Object.assign({},trip);
      newTrip.VenueId = 0;
      newTrip.VenuePegId = 0;
      return newTrip;
    }
    return trip;
  });
```

Comment: JSON parse/stringify is terribly inefficient for cases like this. And 2 still mutates even though it returns an new object after, so it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: My bad, didnt saw that he's modifiying the object. edited the answer

Comment: Now they both fix the problem, but are still less efficient than they could be. In 2, you create a new object regardless of whether or not the `trip` is being updated. To optimize, you could move the `newTrip` inside of the `if`, and return it there. And then return the original `trip` in an else.

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) this is a good technique to replace the spread by when it fails to do a deep copy